# Use CompareValidator to compare dates in mm/dd/yy format

Tags: asp.net, validation

I need to validate a form to compare two date fields in mm/dd/yy format. It seems CompareValidator accepts date only in mm/dd/yyyy formats for comparing dates. Is there any way I can validate the date fields without using javascipt?

Comment: You want to validate dates in C#?

Comment: It is culture related setting. Please see http://forums.asp.net/t/1096556.aspx?How+to+use+compare+validator+with+dd+MM+yyyy+format+of+date

Comment: @husnain_sys Which culture should I set for the mm/dd/yy format?

Comment: Honestly i dont know much about that format culture, but i think that UK (gd-GB). However, that format is under lot of criticism due to its confusing 2 digit and structure.